# jQuery Mobile not working in WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and html5. I want to include my page DIstance2.html in webview, but it's showing like an html page, not a jQuery mobile page. This my code in Android using a webview, version of my jQuery mobile is 1.4.1 and jQuery 1.11.

```
package com.example.webapp.com;

import com.example.webapp.com.R.string;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String url="http://192.168.1.4/dream-html5/api/Distance2html.html";
        WebView wvSite = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);


        //...on active JavaScript...
        wvSite.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvSite.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        //...et on charge la page

        wvSite.loadUrl(url);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an asset folder in your project and call your html url from there e.g. 
wvSite.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dream-html5/api/Distance2html.html")